# Broken If statment in SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Ok Im shaking my head at myself as I know this is something obvious but im just not getting it. The query should return 1 result with a matching username and password, then - i just need to check if the column/field "Status" in the row is set to Inactive or Suspended --  If yes then set value of $count and set a $_SESSION value of msg.

As it stands right now the check of Status just doesn't work - Is it because of how I'm comparing the column.field name? $result['Status']?

**my query is as follows:**

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE User_Name='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// Verified E-Mail address check
if ($result['Status']=="Inactive") {$count=5;$_SESSION['msg']=="Not Verified";};
```

Comment: The last code line has an error i have corrected here, but is not the problem: `// Verified E-Mail address check
if ($result['Status']=="Inactive") {$count=5;$_SESSION['msg']="Not Verified";};`

Comment: please tell me password is not in plain text

Comment: For the moment yes, its all local testing environment, wont be when put up live

Comment: that's not how to develop security, oh well enjoy being hacked.

Comment: are you sure its only returning one row?

Comment: @Dagon - Thanks for the useless comment, have great day and enjoy being of no value on this matter

Comment: eAfter you get the $results you need to fetch the rows. `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  do something with $row['Status'] }`  I'll leave for somebody that has time to explain why you shouldnt use `mysql_*` functions to ceate an answer. Also if it returns just 1 row you dont need the while loop

Comment: @user1160022 yes, there is a check for that later in script, but the table only has 1 record in it, so it dont have much of a choice but return 1 record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc` to get an array of data from your query.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE User_Name='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// Verified E-Mail address check

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if ($row['Status']=="Inactive") {$count=5;$_SESSION['msg']=="Not Verified";};
```

Also, my advice is not to use `mysql_` functions at all as they are deprecated from version 5.5. Check out [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or even better [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: It's funny how me and @jcsanyi posted exact same answers and edits at the same time :D

Comment: @GoranLepur You know I tried that at one point and it didn't work, but went back and tried it again after the answers and got it working. So, I don't know, maybe I had something typed wrong - but in any case the answer is correct and thank you fro being helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You need to fetch your data row from the result before you can compare values.

Something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($data['Status'] == 'Inactive') {
    ...
}
```

That being said, there's good reasons **not** to use mysql_* functions.
See this question for more details:
[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/12860140)

Comment: @jcsanyi Also correct JC, in so far as the mysql_*   I'm literally only about 2 weeks into learning/re-learning PHP after about a 6 year absence from that language. So, Im learning by examples, edits and then doing my own, some examples online are still using the mysql_* instead of mysqli_*, but i will work to correct the bad code, thanks for pointing it out.